# qqplot: what parameter should I use to plot the reference line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics, distribution

I'm testing some variable of my system by means of qqplot according to [this](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html) manual. Now my question is: what line should I plot? According to this documentation I have that:

```
Options for the reference line to which the data is compared:

    ‘45’ - 45-degree line

    ‘s’ - standardized line, the expected order statistics are scaled by the standard deviation of the given sample and have the mean added to them

    ‘r’ - A regression line is fit

    ‘q’ - A line is fit through the quartiles.

    None - by default no reference line is added to the plot.
```

Of course `'45'` and `None` are not suitable for my purpose (i.e. finding the correct distribution from my samples), but which are the more suitable?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s about statistics, not programming.